# Let $H\le G$ be groups such that $x^2 \in H$ for all $x\in G$. Show that $H\unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, problem-solving, normal-subgroups

There is a very standard problem in normal subgroups which is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup such that $x^2 \in H$ for all $x\in G$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

In any book you will find it solved in examples but the solution is kind of mechanical and I think one must mug the solution if one wants to do this on one's own.

The solution given in all standard books is anyhow manipulating $ghg^{-1}$ so that it takes the form $(g^{-1})^2h^{-1}(hg)^2,$ which cannot be done by anyone unless they memorise it.

> So basically I am looking for an intuitive proof of this theorem.

Can someone please suggest me an alternative proof that is based more on intuition and less on memorisation?

Comment: Let me motivate that factorisation. Suppose we take any $h\in H$ and any $g\in G$. Now, the only information about $H$ that we have is that $x^2\in H$ for all $x\in H.$ So, in order to show $ghg^{-1}\in H,$ we wish to make $g$ and $g^{-1}$ part of some square (because $h\in H$ but $g$ is 'any' element of $G$). Since we don't assume anything more (e.g. commutativity) the only way to make $g, g^{-1}$ part of some square is to write $ghg^{-1}$ as $(gh)^2 (h^{-1} g^{-1})g^{-1}$ or $g(g h^{-1}) (h g^{-1})^2.$ I think this is intuitive enough, for one who is studying normal subgroups.

Comment: Not everyone who does mathematics is a man. Consider using gender neutral language such as "they" and "person" instead of "he" and "sir" when talking about others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N = \langle g^2 \mid g \in G \rangle$. Then $N \unlhd G$ and $N \le H$. But groups of exponent $2$ are abelian (that's a standard elementary exercise) so $G/N$ is abelian and hence $H/N \unlhd G/N \Rightarrow H \unlhd G$.

Comment: @AdityaGhosh is there some other way?